# Custom CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I create Custom CollectionViewCell with that code and have lags then I use it. Why ?

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self)
{
        self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    _webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    _webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
    _webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
    _webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    _webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.webView];
        self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        self.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.imageView];
}
return self;
```

If I use this code all ok

```
 - (CollectionCell *)collectionView:(IndexedCollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

cell.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
[cell.contentView addSubview:cell.imageView];
```

Comment: You should learn about the [time profiler](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?include=418#418).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are allocating a webview inside your initialization, I'm going to guess that's why you're seeing the lag.

`UIWebView` is a heavy allocation to make and since it's within a custom cell, it's probably getting called multiple times. See where I'm going?

As I stated in my comment, it's tough to really know what's going inside your application without some result from [Time Profiler](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/TimeProfilerInstrument/TimeProfilerInstrument.html).

Comment: Sorry, that page cannot be found.